# Proving a shifting inequality

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

> Given $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \dots \geq a_{k+l} \geq 0,$ prove the shifting inequality 
>   $$\sqrt{a_{l+1}^2 + \dots + a_{l+k}^2} \leq c_{k,l}(a_1 + \dots + a_k),~~~~~\textrm{where}~~c_{k,l}:=\max\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{4l}}  \right).$$

This is from [Foucart and Rauhut's book](http://human-robot.sysu.edu.cn/ebook/preprint093.pdf), page 173. Any help in solving this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if $k\le l$, then $c_{k,l}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ and $c_{k,l}(a_1+\cdots +a_k)\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}ka_l\ge \sqrt{a_{l+1}^2+\cdots a_{l+k}^2}$.

Now if $k\ge l+1$, then the inequality is equivalent to $c_{k,l}^2(a_1+\cdots +a_k)^2\ge a_{l+1}^2+\cdots a_{l+k}^2$, and it remains to prove that 
$$c_{k,l}^2((l+1)a_{l+1}+a_{l+2}+\cdots +a_k)^2\ge a_{l+1}^2+\cdots +a_{k-1}^2+(l+1)a_k^2$$
Since LHS-RHS is a concave function with respect to  $a_{l+2},\cdots a_{k-1}$, we only need to prove
$$c_{k,l}^2((l+1)a_{l+1}+(k-l-1)a_k)^2\ge (a_{l+1}^2+ka_k^2)$$
and
$$c_{k,l}^2((k-1)a_{l+1}+a_k)^2\ge ka_{l+1}^2+a_k^2$$
Can you get it from this?

Comment: thank you. I still don't see it, I'll try.

Comment: @ManMath once you reduce the inequality to 2 variables, it's easy to examine all the cases.

Comment: This helped. Thank you very much.