# Proving a given inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Given $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \dots \geq a_{k+\ell} \geq 0,$ how to prove the given inequality:
>   $$\sqrt{a_{l+1}^2 + \dots + a_{l+k}^{2}} \leq c_{k,l} (a_1 + \dots + a_k),$$
>   where 
>   $$c_{k, l} :=\max \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} , \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 l}} \right).$$

I tried to consider the cases where $\sqrt{k} < \sqrt{4 l}$ and $\sqrt{k} \geq \sqrt{4 l}.$ It didn't give me the solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020825/proving-a-shifting-inequality